# Validate enumeration based on date ranges in XSD 1.0?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation, xsd-1.0

In XSD I would like to define a type `Country` including a restriction which sets the list of country names that can be used.
Which can be done easily by using enumeration as a restriction.

However, this list will vary when time goes by. For example: in the past we had Yugoslavia which doesn't exist anymore; Croatia, Slovenia, etc appeared instead.
So a country will have a start date and (potentially) an end date. `StartDate` and `EndDate` will set the date range of  existence for each particular country.

When validating an XML I would like to verify whether the XML refers to an existing country.
Therefore the XML will also contain variable `ReferenceDate` which will be used to check against StartDate and EndDate.

Actually I would like to define type `Country` with attributes `CountryName`, `StartDate` and `Enddate` set.
When validating the XML with - for example - values Croatia and `ReferenceDate` I would like to verify whether Croatia is a valid country at date `ReferenceDate`, using type `Country` being defined in the XSD.

Any ideas with the restriction given that I'm using XSD 1.0?

Answer (score 0):

### XSD 1.0

Your constraints cannot be enforced.

### XSD 1.1

You can write an assertion to ensure `current-date()` is within a range of values in the XML instance document.  You cannot make assertions over ranges given by types within the XSD.

Your constraints as stated would probably be best enforced via custom application code.

Comment: the problem is I cannot use XSD 1.1 because not every participant in the process can cope with that

Comment: The problem is that your constraints cannot be expressed in XSD 1.0, or even XSD 1.1 alone, as I mentioned in the answer.  If you still want to validate the constraints you describe, you'll have to do it apart from XSD validation using, for example, XSLT or Schematron or other-language-based validation.

Comment: yes, you're completely right. I will actually use XSLT to process the XML file. So the XML file will contain value Croatia for Country and ReferenceDate YMD. In what way would you list all countries with their StartDates and EndDates to make these accessible by XSLT?

Comment: I'd advise you to wrap up this question, accepting an answer that's helped you the most at this point, and raise a new question, but only after attempting such an XSLT program first.  As usual here, it's best to focus on particular impasses that rather than requesting broad design guidance.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider a framework that allows you to generate the schema appropriate to a particular date (typically by applying an XSLT transformation to some kind of meta-schema).

For example, your meta-schema could be essentially an XSD file where any element can have start-date and end-date attributes, and you could process this very easily using XSLT to retain only the elements that apply on a particular date.

Comment: I did consider such a thing, the problem - however - is that each XML which needs to be validated - may have another reference date (I was not very clear at that point since I used ActualDate). Which would result in many lists